# Multi process loop not working as expected

Tags: pi-3, python, tkinter

I am working on project where i interfaced two MCP4725 dac with my Pi for sending set point to my two PID device i.e (rpm pid and torque pid) at same time .So i used multi threading concept but i am stuck in for loop as my set point should go in ramp fashion as per user given time(secs).for example in 10 secs the set point value should reach from 0-desired value.

```
import Adafruit_MCP4725
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.title("User interface monitor")
rpm=tk.StringVar()
tim=tk.StringVar()
tim1=tk.StringVar()
tor=tk.StringVar()
dac=Adafruit_MCP4725.MCP4725(address=0x60)
dac1=Adafruit_MCP4725.MCP4725(address=0x61)
def enter():
  global rpm,tim,tim1,tor
  root.rpmLabel=tk.Label(root,text='enter rpm value:')
  root.rpmLabel.grid(row=0)
  root.torLabel=tk.Label(root,text="enter torque value in percentage: ")
  root.torLabel.grid(row=1)
  root.timeLabel=tk.Label(root,text="enter Ramp time in secs:")
  root.timeLabel.grid(row=2)
  root.timeLabel1=tk.Label(root,text="enter Steady time in secs:")
  root.timeLabel1.grid(row=3)
  root.e1=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=rpm)
  root.e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
  root.e1.delete(0,"end")
  root.e2=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=tor)
  root.e2.grid(row=1,column=1)
  root.e2.delete(0,"end")
  root.e3=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=tim)
  root.e3.grid(row=2,column=1)
  root.e3.delete(0,"end")
  root.e4=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=tim1)
  root.e4.grid(row=3,column=1)
  root.e4.delete(0,"end")
def gett():
   global rpm,tim,tim1,tor
  #try:
   rpm=int(root.e1.get())
   tor=int(root.e2.get())
   tim=float(root.e3.get())
   tim1=float(root.e4.get())
   print("rpm is: ",rpm)
   print("Torque in % is: ",tor)
   print("Ramp time is: ",tim)
   print("steady time is: ",tim1)
   root.rpmLabel.destroy()
   root.e1.destroy()
   root.torLabel.destroy()
   root.e2.destroy()
   root.timeLabel.destroy()
   root.e3.destroy()
   root.e4.destroy()
   root.timeLabel1.destroy()
   #root.e3.destroy()
   t1=threading.Thread(target=getRpm)
   t2=threading.Thread(target=getTor)
   t1.start()
   t2.start()
   #except Exception:
   #print("invalid command")
   #pass
def getRpm():
   global rpm,tim,tim1
   val=int((rpm/2)+1)
   t=float((tim/val)/2)
   print(t)
   for x in range(0,val,1):
     dac.set_voltage(x)
     vlt=x/4096*5.0
     y=time.ctime()
     y=y[10:-4]
     time.sleep(t)
     if(x==0):
      z=y
     if(x==val-1):
      s=y
   time.sleep(tim1)
   y=time.ctime()
   time.sleep(tim1)
   y=time.ctime()
   y=y[10:-4]
   print(z,x,vlt,s,y)
def getTor():
   global tor,tim,tim1    
   val1=int(4096*(tor/100))
   t1=float((tim/val1)/2)
   print(t1)
   for i in range(0,val1,1):
     dac1.set_voltage(i)
     vlt1=i/4096*5.0
     d=time.ctime()
     d=d[10:-4]
     time.sleep(t1)
     if(i==0):
      e=d
     if(i==val1-1):
      u=d
   time.sleep(tim1)
   d=time.ctime()
   d=d[10:-4]
   print(e,i,vlt1,u,d)
root.Button1=tk.Button(root,text="MODE1",fg="blue",command=enter)
root.Button1.pack()
root.Button1.place(x=200,y=200)
root.Button2=tk.Button(root,text="MODE2",fg="red",command=enter)
root.Button2.pack()
root.Button2.place(x=200,y=230)
root.Button3=tk.Button(root,text="Enter",command=gett)
root.Button3.pack()
root.Button3.place(x=280,y=215)
root.mainloop()
```

But this way loop  completed within 2 secs,which is again not acceptable

```
rpm is:  5000
Torque in % is:  60
Ramp time is:  10.0
steady time is:  11.0
0.0026656004264960682
0.00271333604666938
 15:59:01  2456 2.998046875  15:59:10   15:59:21 
 15:59:01  2500 3.0517578125  15:59:10   15:59:21
```

This is my output from where it is clearly visible that my ramp time is given by user 10 secs but my prog take 9 secs to ramp out value.
Please guys guide me to minimize the error.

Comment: This appears to be a generic programming question.

Comment: @Joan,guide me to control loop.are you getting my issue?

Comment: Your two  loops are confusing. Can you debug by testing a couple of sample points. I mean no looping, just this sample in gives that sample out etc. This way each loop becomes perhaps less than 10 statements. Forget multiple threading for now and just test each thread independently to make sure each of them works, then move on to multi-threading. Or give us a link to the tutorial or demo program, to make it easier for us to debug for you.

Comment: @tlfong01,i tested thread independently also.Independently also it takes 16 secs,as i tested at least 100 different values for `time.sleep()`.

Comment: Is there any other way to give digital values in ramp fashion in particular time frame?

Comment: Ah, let me see.  I once played with PID with trapezoidal (sort of ramp up and down) time functions. Let us eat the big elephant byte by byte, in two bytes.  Let us do the first loop, forget the second loop for now. I usually use an Excel worksheet, manually select sample points, including regular and boundary points and let Excel do the calculation and plot the graph for me. Excel can even do WHAT IF analysis. In other words, for desktop/dry run tests, Excel is my friend.

Comment: You project using I2C 12 bit MCP4725 DAC should be interesting. I also played with MCP4725 for D Type digital audio power amplifier whose volume can be digitally adjusted in fine steps.  So I can play with things like fading in/out etc. But I never thought about doing PID, because in real life everyday situations, the lazy EE guys never do PID, perhaps P only, at most PI. PID is only for the so called engineering scientists in CalTech or MIT. For my Micky Mouse project, playing with P only should already let the Arduino guys not looking down at me that much.

Comment: Ah, you remind me that when I played PID in my Arduino Decimilla days, I actually used a chip with trapezoid function points in ROM (of course no calculation for the timid 8 bit Arduino with ridiculously little 2k RAM.)  Now I have Rpi4B 4GB, so perhaps I can resume my long stalled toy car project. Anyway, thanks for reading my Use of English assignment. Good luck to your project.  Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103503/discussion-between-ram-and-tlfong01).